# R: Two dimensional random walk (do not use package)

Tags: r, random, statistics

Here is the problem:

Consider a two‐dimensional random walk

X_(t+1)=X_t+Z_(t+1),X_0=0

Y_(t+1)=Y_t+W_(t+1),Y_0=0

where, Z_t, W_t, t=0,1,... are independent and identically distributed standard normal
random variables. Simulate and plot the sample path of (X_t, Y_t) for t=0,1,...,100. A
sample is shown below.

So I tried to generate a one-dimensional version.

```
set.seed(13579)
r<-sample(c(-1,1),size=100,replace=T,prob=c(0.5,0.5))
(r<-c(10,r))
(w<-cumsum(r))
w<-as.ts(w)
plot(w,main="random walk")
abline(h=10)
```

But this is not i.i.d., and I am not sure how to combine the sample fuunction with the rnorm(), I stuck here. Could anyone help?

Comment: Do you want to take a sample from a normal distribution? Is that where you stuck?

Comment: Not quite exactly. I want to take t to be the random varible from normal distribution but my final target is to plot the 2-D random walk graph, with X_0=0 and Y_0=0.

Comment: You can go through this one :  `z = c(0,rnorm(100)); x_path <- cumsum(z)`

Comment: Sorry I am not quite follow. Could you please explain a llittle bit more?

Comment: z is the stochastic part of the equation. By puting zero at the beginning, it becomes the initial value of the x. Then if you apply the cumsum function, it becomes the path of the x.  Maybe writing in this way can be more clear: 
`z = rnorm(100); x_path <- cumsum(c(0,z))`

Comment: Umm I tried the following

 set.seed(13579)

(z = rnorm(100))

(x<- cumsum(c(0,z)))

x<-as.ts(x)

plot(x)

It seems work in 1-D case. But I am not sure how to plot random walk in the 2-D case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248595/discussion-between-powerpoint-trenton-and-maydin).